# Flags that result in function calls and passing arguments

Tags: bash, flags, getopts

I would like to update a script that is currently like this:

```
$ example.sh a b
```

Here is the code within `example.sh`

```
for var in "$@"
do
    $var
done
```

Where it takes in arguments and those arguments are looped over and executed (assuming those arguments exist).

I would like to update the script so that these `flags` are the scripts / functions and that everything after is applied as the argument to the function.

```
$ example.sh --a 1 2 3 --b 4 5 6
```

I would like to loop over all flags and run the equivalent of.

```
a 1 2 3
b 1 2 3
```

I have looked into `getopts` but I am not sure if it will allow me to execute and pass in the arguments the way I would like.

What I tried:

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:d:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    a) i=$OPTARG ;;
    b) j=$OPTARG ;;
    c) k=$OPTARG ;;
    d) l=$OPTARG ;;
  esac
done

echo $i
echo $j

for file in "$@"; do
  echo $file
done
```

I found the following script which given `example --a 1 2 3 --b 4 5 6` will only assign the first item using `OPTARG` and it doesn't work properly. I am unsure how to apply arguments to a function in this format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any automatic way to do what you want, but you can just loop through your arguments and construct your commands, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=()
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do                         # loop until no args left
    if [[ $1 = --* ]]; then                    # arg starts with --
        [[ ${#cmd[@]} -gt 0 ]] && "${cmd[@]}"  # execute previous command
        cmd=( "${1#--}" )                      # start new array
    else
        cmd+=( "$1" )                          # append to command
    fi
    shift                                      # remove $1, $2 goes to $1, etc.
done

[[ ${#cmd[@]} -gt 0 ]] && "${cmd[@]}"          # run last command
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this way.

cat example.sh

```
while read line;do
  $line
done <<<$(echo $@ | sed 's/--/\n/g')
```

and I try that

```
./example.sh '--echo 1 2 3 --dc -e 4sili5+p'
```

output

```
1 2 3
9
```

Comment: This is going to misparse any arguments that contain whitespace or shell wildcards or "--".

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes it's not the top answer but we know nothing about the type of cmd, that's why i tell perhaps.